# xsd typing options

Tags: xml, xsd, etl, xsd-validation

i have two opposing requirements related to an xml document and its related xsd.

the background is that i need to extract data from a relational data base, transform the extracted data into xml and then load this xml into a second "remote" database.

the opposing requirements are these

first i want to create/define the xml document and its schema such that it never has to be amended. as i am extracting data from a relational database i was thinking of going for an xml structure such as this

```
<data name="aaa" value="bbb" type="ccc" scale="ddd"/>
```

where name and value will be mandatory and type and scale (e.g. decimal scale) are optional, these last two are only used "when necessary"

secondly i need a strongly typed xsd. this is to ensure the consumer of the loaded xml document doesn’t get any "nasty surprises". and they can generate strongly type java objects to unmarshal the xml document into.

can i have an xml structure shown above and have its xsd strongly typed?

or

is it possible to solve both these requirements in one?
that is:- An extremely flexible xml structure that can cope with any "unknown" data requirements in the future along with extremely strong data typing?

what is the best compromise solution?

Comment: can't help. Its you who should decide to go STRICT or LIBERAL about validation rules .. (to be more generic ...) as per your business rules.

Comment: thats what i was worried about... is there no "clever" xsd options at all?

Comment: Is there no style of xml document with its related xsd, that delivers extreme flexibility in the xml document coupled with strong xsd typing?

Comment: Not only XSD, but for everyother validation tools you would be disappointed. Or probably you are interpreting in wrong ways. Can you provide a **clear** example for this requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am still not very clear with your requirement:

 Here I go with some of the features available with XSD.

For going liberal, there are some options like
1) XSD:any that allows any element(s) and anyAttribute allows any attributes for a particular node.
2) You can make an element optional by using `minOccurs='0'`, for attributes `use='Optional'`
3) declaring datatype as string will allow it to be null. if its date/datetime then define a simpleType with pattern MM/DD/YYYY etc, and use it as TYPE, so that you can allow null data as well. (Blank tag)
4) usage of `<xsd:All/>` instead of `<xsd:sequence/>` allows you to have elements in any order.

For going strict
1) Use minOccurs='1' for a tag that is must .. by default every element will have minOccurs='1' unless you declare.

2) Use minLength='1' to force a tag to have a value, so that it won't be null

I will list few more if I get flashed with any :)

Comment: i tried to give a clear example in a comment but it wouldnt fit

Answer (score 0):

hopefully this is a clear example:-

I have approx 50 million users.
Each user can have hundreds of associated data items, currently approx 500 data items. most of which are optional.

I have to extract these data items from one database and load into a second remote database.

Over time additional user data items will be added to this extract and load process.
I want this process of adding additional user data items to be lean. e.g. quick and cheap, easy to test,
easy to deploy to production

I decided to transform these hundreds of data items into a complete xml document, one xml document per user,
using the format shown in my original question.

this xml format can cope with any new user data items without EVER having to change.
this means when new data items are added, i do not have to worry about deploying a new version of the xsd.

however i also would like to have strongly type data validation. i do not believe the xml format shown above
can be used with a strongly typed xsd.

I dont need to stick with XML, JSON format would also satisfy my requirement of having a structure that can cope
with data item additions, however i do not know of a way of validating JSON in the same way an xsd can be used
to validate its related XML documents.

Comment: Over time additional user data items will be added to this! So you wouldn't know what these additional element/attribute tags are?

Comment: Well. If you already know the element/attribute names those possibly would appear in future. You can added them up making them optional. Indeed you can make many other data in your existing current XML as optional too.

Comment: coming to 2nd requirement. **Strong type** you say. Well that is part of Data validation and XSD is champ in that .. you can apply restriction on pattern, constraint list! on date, datetime, names etc everything can be validated.

Comment: Making elements/attributes optional and forcing data to be proper is the best suggestion I can provide .. that is incase if you know what **possible data you can have**

Comment: that is correct, over time the additional data items that COULD be added to this ETL process are UNKNOWN

Comment: Then better you don't validate :) I don't think any Technology would support this! after-all its machine that has to work :)